# Programmatically get the version of an IntelliJ IDEA plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Is there a way to programmatically get the version of an IntelliJ IDEA plugin?

I'm creating my own IntelliJ IDEA plugin, and I have set the version property in the plugin.xml(e.g.:`<version>3.1.1</version>`). I need to get the version to display in the "About" dialog of my plugin. Is there a way to get this value programmatically?

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA plugin development, if there is a different way to display a version number please let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go mate:

```
PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginId.getId("my.plugin.id")).getVersion();
```

Edit: from 2020, use

```
PluginManagerCore.getPlugin
```

Comment: How to get the version of Intellij Idea (not the plugin) programmatically?

Comment: @Junius ask that as a separate question and I'll answer it ;)

Comment: thx for the answer. `PluginManager.getPlugin` was deprecated with build 193.2252. It still exists as of 2020.3 pending removal but was internally replaced by `PluginManagerCore.getPlugin`. Once removal is executed compatibility issues will unfortunately occur.